# How to print elements from an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, formatting

I have an array with elements, for example array = ["example1", "example2", "example3"].

How can I print it in the following format?

1. example1 2. example2 3. example 3...

Answer (score 22):

Use `forEach` for this like below

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
});
```

Comment: How does this even come close to answering the question? When run, it prints "a, "b", and "c" on separate lines. E.g., how does this print out the item numbers? Can you explain your answer, please? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54134964/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 15):

You can use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  document.writeln((i+1) + ": " + array[i]);
```

And use the `document.writeln` to print it out. See the below working snippet.

**Snippet**

```js
array = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  document.writeln((i+1) + ": " + array[i]);
```

> **Note:**
>   The `document.writeln()` is implemented differently many times. So you should use:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("id_of_div").innerHTML += (i+1) + ": " + array[i];
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Use forEach for this like below(ES6)

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element)
    }
);
```

Comment: Like [Vivek Kasture's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198429/how-to-print-elements-from-an-array-with-javascript/54134964#54134964), this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of printing in a loop, I'd propose a simple **functional transformation** to generate a string that you can print (or use in another way):

```js
var example = ["example1", "example2", "example3"]
var O = example.map( (e, i) => (i + 1 + "." + e) ).join(' ');
console.log(O);
```

It works by applying a [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your array, with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to combine each array element `e` and its index `i` into a string.  You then just need to [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements of the resulting array, using any separator you want (e.g. ' ').

Comment: Yes, explicit loops shouldn't be necessary for simple cases like this.

Comment: Will it scale? Or is there a [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) hidden in there (building a long string with short strings and reallocation & copy for every append)? Not a rhetorical question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks for the edit - why shouldn't it scale: https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a *for* loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    console.log(i + ". " + array[i]);
```

Comment: That outups in multiple strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard array methods to get the result you're after. MDN has some great documentation on [array iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Iteration_methods).

```
var examples = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];

// You can use reduce to transform the array into result,
// appending the result of each element to the accumulated result.
var text = examples.reduce(function (result, item, index) {
    var item_number = index + 1;

    return result + " " + item_number + ". " + item;
}, "");

// You can use a variable with forEach to build up the
// result - similar to a for loop
var text = "";

examples.forEach(function (item, index) {
    var item_number = index + 1;

    text = text + " " + item_number + ". " + item;
});

// You can map each element to a new element which 
// contains the text you'd like, then join them
var text = examples.map(function (item, index) {
    var item_number = index + 1;
    return item_number + ". " + item;
}).join(" ");

// You can put them into an HTML element using document.getElementById
document.getElementById("example-text-result").innerHTML = text;

// or print them to the console (for node, or in your browser) 
// with console.log
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
var arr = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3']
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log((i + 1) + '. ' + arr[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to print it out in one line:

```
let exampleArray = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
let result = [];

 for (let i = 0; i < exampleArray.length; i++) {    
   result += i + 1 + ". " + exampleArray[i] + " ";
 }
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents:

```js
let array = [
  [
    ['a', 'b', ['c', 13, ['d', 22, [44, [34]]]]],
    [1, 2, 3]
  ],
  [],
  [
    ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    [4, 5, 6, 7]
  ]
];

console.log(printArray(array));

function printArray(inputArr) {
  return "[" + _printArray(inputArr).intermediateVal + "]";
}

function _printArray(inputArr) {
  if (Array.isArray(inputArr)) {
    let str = "";
    for (let a = 0; a < inputArr.length; a++) {
      let result = _printArray(inputArr[a]);
      if (result.isComplexType) {
        str += "[" + result.intermediateVal + "]";
      } else {
        str += result.intermediateVal;
      }
      if (a + 1 < inputArr.length) {
        str += ", ";
      }
    }

    return {
      "isComplexType": true,
      "intermediateVal": str
    }
  } else {
    return {
      "isComplexType": false,
      "intermediateVal": inputArr
    }
  }
}
```

and prints this:

```
[[[a, b, [c, 13, [d, 22, [44, [34]]]]], [1, 2, 3]], [], [[d, e, f, g, h], [4, 5, 6, 7]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was solving such a problem and I did this

```
const multiLanguages = ["C is fun", "Python is cool",  "JavaScript is amazing"];
for (let i = 0; i < multiLanguages.length; i++) {
  console.log(multiLanguages[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in ES6 reduce will be good choice you over map. It declares predefined variable for you and event you don't need to join()

```js
var array = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
var op= array.reduce((ac,cur,ind)=> ac +` ${ind+1}.` + cur,'');
console.log(op);
```

With Map() and Join()

```js
var array = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
var op= array.map((e, i) =>`${i+1}.${e}`).join(' ');
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayToString = (arr) => {
    return arr.join(" ");
};

const array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 34];
const result = arrayToString(array);
console.log(result);
```